# Regex in pandas not removing anything from column?

Tags: regex, pandas, jupyter-notebook, python-3.4

I am trying to remove everything in one column after the "-" as part of my clean up of a csv.

My regex works on notepad++ tests as I expect it to. But when I run this in my code it does not remove anything. I have tried numerous combinations and nothing is ever removed. Quite baffled.

```
df['Product Num Out'].replace("-[^-]*$","", regex=True)
Also tried
df['Product Num Out'].str.replace("-[^-]*$","")

Product Num Out (sample)
MX111-fxfxfxfxfv
Px999-gfgfgfgss
```

Comment: Did you try `df['Product Num Out'] = df['Product Num Out'].replace("-[^-]*$","", regex=True)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df['Product Num Out'] = df['Product Num Out'].replace("-[^-]*$","", regex=True)
```

This worked, I don't quite understand why because I have not had to do this with my other edits for csv, for example

```
df['Abuse/NFF'].replace("-", "Faulty", inplace=True)
```

Anyone explain this?

Comment: Because you used `inplace=True`... You can use `df['Product Num Out'].replace("-[^-]*$","", regex=True, inplace=True)`